# Node.js: How to check if folder is empty or not with out uploading list of files

Tags: file, node.js, directory, fs

I am using `Node.js`.

I want to check if **folder is empty** or not? One option is to use **fs.readdir** but it loads whole bunch of files into an array. 
I have more than 10000 files in the folder. Loading files name is useless just to check if folder is empty or not. So looking for alternate solution.

Answer (score 13):

How about using nodes native `fs` module http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback. It's `readdir` and `readdirSync` functions provide you with an array of all the included file names (excluding `.` and `..`). If the length is `0` then your directory is empty.

Comment: He wants to avoid the call to fs,readdir() becoz the target dir may contain *lot of* files.

Comment: I know, but at the time the question was posted this was not a requirement. I thought I'd leave it for reference purposes.

Answer (score 12):

This is an ugly hack but I'll throw it out there anyway. You could just call `fs.rmdir` on the directory. If the callback returns an error which contains `code: 'ENOTEMPTY'`, it was not empty. If it succeeds then you can call `fs.mkdir` and replace it. This solution probably only makes sense if your script was the one which created the directory  in the first place, has the proper permissions, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can execute any *nix shell command from within NodeJS by using exec(). So for this you can use the good old 'ls -A ${folder} | wc -l' command (which lists all files/directories contained within ${folder} hiding the entries for the current directory (.) and parent directory (..) from the output which you want to exclude from the count, and counting their number).

For example in case ./tmp contains no files/directories below will show 'Directory ./tmp is empty.'. Otherwise, it will show the number of files/directories that it contains.

```
var dir = './tmp';
exec( 'ls -A ' + dir + ' | wc -l', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if( !error ){
        var numberOfFilesAsString = stdout.trim();
        if( numberOfFilesAsString === '0' ){
            console.log( 'Directory ' + dir + ' is empty.' );
        }
        else {
            console.log( 'Directory ' + dir + ' contains ' + numberOfFilesAsString + ' files/directories.' );
        }
    }
    else {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Comment: plusone: This is the "best" way to accomplish the goal given the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate from my answer in [how to determine whether the directory is empty directory with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217271/how-to-determine-whether-the-directory-is-empty-directory-with-nodejs/60037392#60037392)

There is the possibility of using the `opendir` method call that creates an iterator for the directory.

This will remove the need to read all the files and avoid the potential memory & time overhead

```
    import {promises as fsp} from "fs"
    const dirIter = await fsp.opendir(_folderPath);
    const {value,done} = await dirIter[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next();
    await dirIter.close()
```

The done value would tell you if the directory is empty

Answer (score 0):

What about globbing? ie, `exists myDir/*`. It is not supported out of box by node (TOW v0.10.15), but  bunch of modules will do that for you, like [minimatch](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/minimatch)

Answer (score 0):

Just like to add that there's a node module [extfs](https://github.com/codexar/npm-extfs) which can be used to check if a directory is empty using the function **isEmpty()** as shown by the code snippet below:

```
var fs = require('extfs');

fs.isEmpty('/home/myFolder', function (empty) {
  console.log(empty);
});
```

Check out the link for documentation regarding the synchronous version of this function.

Comment: extfs' isEmpty function also uses fs.readDir internally. So, it will anyway load all file names. https://github.com/codexar/npm-extfs/blob/master/extfs.js#L65-70