# How to check if directory is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Node.js for backend. I want to check if the directory is empty then send any response to the client like `res.json('it is empty')` or `res.sendStatus(404)` otherwise do something ...because on my client side (Reactjs), my app keeps waiting for the response for few mins.

Node.js responds with JSON if folder is not empty and works correctly, but does not respond for empty folder.

**Nodejs:**

```
var dirTree = ('./data/');

var diretoryTreeToObj = function(dir, done, res) {
  var results = [];

  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list, res) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);

    var pending = list.length;

    if (!pending && pending !== 0)
      return done(null, {
        name: path.basename(dir),
        type: 'folder',
        children: results
      });

    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          let data2 = __dirname + dir + '/' + path.basename(file)
          let dirName = data2.split('\\').pop().split('/data/').pop()
          results.push({
            name: dirName,
            type: 'folder',
          });
          if (!--pending)
            done(null, results);
        } else {
          let data3 = __dirname + dir + '/' + path.basename(file)
          let contentName = data3.split('\\').pop().split('/data/').pop()
          results.push({
            name: contentName,
            type: 'file'
          });
          if (!--pending)
            done(null, results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

app.get('/source/:fileid(*)', (req, res) => {
  const {
    fileid
  } = req.params;
  var allFiles = __dirname + /data/ + fileid
  diretoryTreeToObj(allFiles, (err, getDirs) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.json(getDirs);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: your if condition is wrong try this if (pending == 0)

Comment: @Dineshundefined can u give an example?

Answer (score 0):

the if condition should be:

```
if (!pending){
  return done(null, {
    name: path.basename(dir),
    type: 'folder',
    children: results
  });
}
```

check this:
[how to determine whether the directory is empty directory with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217271/how-to-determine-whether-the-directory-is-empty-directory-with-nodejs)